# Turn on and on Wi-Fi adapter after each period of time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, adapter

This sounds weird, but my wifi pc kept disconnecting after 15min of downloading a certain file and it does not connect back until I restart Wi-Fi adapter, for this reason I am looking for a methode that restarts my adapter after each 15min.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely you would be better fixing the problem with your WIFI disconnecting?  Regardless, you really need to advise your Operating System, and it would be useful to know details of your WIFI adapter.

Comment: Amen @davidgo .. that was the first comment to my answer I posted the same minute you posted the comment. :)  I told them how to do it nonetheless.

Comment: That's a bad idea : It means you cannot maintain a connection more than 15 minutes, so downloading a large file becomes impossible.

Answer (score 3):

This is a HORRIBLE way to go about solving your problem.
What *should be* asked is why is this happening and how to fix it, but a hacky workaround has been requested:

The adapter can be reset with something as simple as the commands from Step 1, but what's needed is a way to schedule these two commands to be run every fifteen minutes; while there are a few methods to do so, the simplest thing that comes to mind is to use Task Scheduler:

1. Create a batch file with:

   ```
   netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" disabled
   netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" enabled
   ```
2. Run it to ensure it works
3. <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> → `Task scheduler`
4. Right-click *Task Scheduler (local)* → *Create Task*

   1. *General* tab: Set a *Name* and select *Run only when user is logged in*
   2. *Triggers* tab: *New...* → *Repeat task every 15 minutes*
   3. *Actions* tab: *New...* → *Start a Program* → *Program/script:* select batch file from Step 1
   4. Poke through the remaining options and tweak as desired
5. *OK*

Comment: BTW, if you need help with any of these steps, I will add those steps to my answer

Comment: Since #3 will show differently based on OS version, a better way to do so would be `WinKey`+`R`, as `Task Scheduler (local)` doesn't show in Win1o Pro 21H2 via Search _(`Task Scheduler` does)_ and right-clicking on `Task Scheduler` doesn't show _Create Task_.

Comment: l REALLY like your edits. @JW0914  Especially the dope buttons. :) Thanks!

Comment: Task Scheduler part is done, but the batch file doesn't restart the adapter when I run it. Is it possible the adapter's name is wrong?
At Network Connections Center I see that its name is "Wi-Fi 3" and I cannot change it!

Answer (score 1):

As Señor CMasMas said, Task Scheduler has to be used to run every 15 minutes, and `powershell` or `devcon`, which is faster, can be executed from there:

1. `.ps1` script:

   ```powershell
   if (-Not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) {
    if ([int](Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BuildNumber) -ge 6000) {
     $CommandLine = "-File `"" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "`" " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
     Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $CommandLine
     Exit
    }
   }

   $d = Get-PnpDevice| where {$_.friendlyname -like "NAME-OF-YOUR-ADAPTER*"};
   $d  | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false;
   $d  | Enable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
   ```
2. Using `Devcon`:

   ```powershell
   devcon restart "<Device-ID>*"
   ```

---

I experienced the same issue you are describing and the problem in my case was quite simple: the WiFi card had no official driver for Windows 10 and using older drivers caused the problem *(the WiFi card worked perfectly on Linux, Windows7 and Windows 8.1)*:

- I used these methods to reset it, but eventually gave up and changed the network card, otherwise you won't be able of downloading large files
- Another turn around is using the Bluetooth network option, connecting to your phone via its Bluetooth network connection

Comment: General FYI: drivers for Windows ≤8.1 will almost never work correctly in Windows ≥10 due to programming changes that occurred between the two OSes _(usually drivers from Windows ≤8.1 will cause BSODs in Windows ≥10 - this was/is problematic when folks were trying to use OEM drivers for PC/laptops that shipped with Windows 8 but we're EoL [End of Life] by the time Windows 10 was released - in such cases, it's recommended to download the driver directly from the component manufacturer's site or use Windows Update to install the correct driver)_.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution JW0914.